# How to install twig.vim in the .vimrc file for Vim 8.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, editor

I'm trying to get this installed in my vim for ubuntu:

https://github.com/nelsyeung/twig.vim

I downloaded the files to ~/.vim folder, but there are no instructions on what I need to put into the .vimrc file to get it activated. What steps am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "get it activated"? Anyway, use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: activated as in turning on the plugin so my twig files have highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded the files to ~/.vim folder,

No. If you want to use Vim new integrated plugins management, first create the pack directory with a dedicated subdirectory of your choice (let's call it `git-plugins` but it's really own to you and depend how you want to have things organised)

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/git-plugins
```

In that location, create one of these directories:

- `start` for plugins you always want available when you launch Vim
- `opt` for plugins you want to activate and deactivate manually

Last, there will be a directory for the plugin itself. So, here, you have to download the files into let's say `~/.vim/pack/git-plugins/start/twig/`

> instructions on what I need […] to get it activated.

Now, launch vim and type the following command:

```
:packloadall
```

Check the included manual with

```
:h packl
```

This plugin has no doc to integrate into that system. But for general cases, put the following in your `~/.vimrc`, after all internal setting and before plugins dedicated settings.

```
packloadall
silent! helptags ALL
```